# In bash what does ! (exclamation mark) before command means?

Tags: shell, command-line-interface

I just mispelled command

```
git status
```

with

```
!git status
```

Console showed it started cloning last cloned repository into folder status...

My question is, what does this command mean and does it have any usage?

Comment: Please read this: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/3747/understanding-the-exclamation-mark-in-bash
The issue here is not the git command, but the exclamation mark at the beginning

Answer (score 28, accepted):

In bash, if you type `!` followed by a command name, it will substitute it with the last command in your history starting by that name.

So in your case `!git` was substituted with `git clone somerepo` so the whole line was translated to `git clone somerepo status`

Comment: Thanks, i know its stupid question but i was wondering what happened... and if i somehow damaged my cloned repository

Comment: Could you please also link to a [documentation page](https://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/) that covers this syntax?

Comment: This is a curious feature. But in what situations is it useful? I usually just press the up arrow to find a command I have previously executed, and in a script I would probably consider it almost always better to write the entire expression explicitly since it is much clearer what happens. Also, it feels like using `!` in this way is a little bit like gambling, since it might accidentally execute another command than the one you expect to execute, unless you don't have a perfect recollection of the latest commands you have executed (at least I wouldn't trust my own memory enough).

Comment: regarding usefulness, e.g. you do 

`grep someString foo.txt`

not knowing yet what result you get. you hit a low number of occurrences and want to know context, so you do`

`!grep -A 10 -B 10` to print 10 lines before and after your matches.